# SQL: How to conditionally define the code that contains linked server ID only for some server instances?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, linked-server

I am writing a data pump as a stored procedure on SQL Server. It is expected to extract some data from Sybase, and UPDATE or INSERT the table in SQL Server database.

For development, the source table is stored in the test database on the same SQL Server as the target table is (in different database). On the production site, the Sybase server is connected as a linked server.

How can write common code (for the installation script) that would work both on the testing site, and on the production site?

See the fragment... and the details below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_data_pump
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @@servername = 'COMPUTER\SQLTESTINSTANCE' BEGIN
        -- for development
        MERGE dbo.sometable AS tar
        USING (SELECT code, data
               FROM dbtest.dbo.datapump_sometable) AS source    -- !!!!
            ON tar.code = source.code
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
            SET tar.data = source.data,
                tar.changed = GETDATE(),
                tar.changedby = 'datapump'
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (data, created, createdby)
            VALUES (source.code, source.data, GETDATE(), 'datapump');
    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- for the deployed application
        MERGE dbo.sometable AS tar
        USING (SELECT data
               FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSRVID, 'SELECT * FROM xdb.schema.xxx_sometable')) AS source -- !!!!
            ON tar.code = source.code
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
            SET tar.data = source.data,
                tar.changed = GETDATE(),
                tar.changedby = 'datapump'
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (data, created, createdby)
            VALUES (source.code, source.data, GETDATE(), 'datapump');
    END
END
```

The Sybase database contains a view to access the data; however, the view can be called only through `OPENQUERY(LINKEDSRVID, 'SELECT ....')`. Because of this, the `LINKEDSRVID` must exist. However, it is not created on the development site, therefore the code does not compile.

The core of the problem can be simplified to pseudo code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_data_pump
AS
BEGIN
    IF @@servername = 'COMPUTER\SQLTESTINSTANCE' BEGIN
        -- for development
        ...
        SELECT * FROM dbtest.dbo.datapump_sometable) AS source
        ...
    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- for the deployed application
        ...
        SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSRVID, 'SELECT * FROM xdb.schema.xxx_sometable')) AS source
        ...
    END
END
```

How the problem should be solved?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for pointing to the `sp_` problem. I really thought that it is _just a convention for naming a "stored procedure"_ (as the second article tells), and I was not aware about the reasons for the performance penalty (the lookup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could wrap the code in dynamic SQL to avoid the compile error, I suggest you create a linked server named `LINKEDSRVID` in dev and just include `OPENQUERY` in the proc.  Ideally, that should point to a test Sybase instance but you could create one for the dbtest database instead if that's not an option.  Just be aware that testing won't be totally valid if you don't have a Sybase test instance.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually, I have ended with generating the SQL code dynamically because of DRY principle.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just need to create a fake linked server in your dev environment to imitate live... You can do this by creating a linked server connection using the SQL Native drivers which can have any name but set the source to localhost. The link is just to itself and not functional, just there for development.

Eg;

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'LiveServerName', 
    @srvproduct=N'', 
    @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
    @datasrc=N'localhost' --just to imitate the connection
```

Also create the database and other tables/objects on localhost for the sake of validation of the 4 part "remote" reference.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for you help.